# Is it possible to tell what user account created a file?

Tags: windows-server-2003

I'm trying to debug which user (windows account) is responsible for actually writing a file from my ASP.NET site.  When I set the permissions on the folder to `everyone`, I can write to the directory.  When I set the permissions to my account, `NETWORK SERVICE`, or `ASPNET` I cannot write to the share.  How can I determine what user is writing *or* trying to write to the share given a file?

The event log doesn't show any details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable object access auditing (via Local Security Policy or GPO) and then configure auditing entries on the Advanced Security settings of the shared folder.